# Limit amount of elements a stream is processing at one time

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How can one in AKKA limit the amount of elements currently present in a (part of) the stream without having to drop any elements?

Comment: Hard work is appreciated at stack overlow. Please provide some code that you're stuck with and cannot move forward.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is referred to as an overflow strategy. In the [documentation you link to](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-rate.html#buffers-in-akka-streams) The first example shows the overflow strategy that you want: `OverflowStrategy.backpressure`

Akka streams are reactive, which means that by setting your overflow strategy to backpressure you're telling the producer you're connected to that you can't consume any more data right now. This will however only work if everything upstream of you can handle the fact you're not going to process any more elements.

In your case something like this should work since our `Source` can be backpressured:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.duration._

implicit val system = ActorSystem()

FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(...))
  .via(Compression.gunzip())
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 255))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .buffer(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .throttle(elements = 1, per = 1.second)
  .to(Sink.foreach(println))
  .run()
```

It's easy to see backpressure in action with this very simple example. Since w're using `throttle` the flow will backpressure the upstream so that only 1 element is emitted per second. Given a big enough input file this should quickly fill up the 10 element buffer.

If you swap to using `OverflowStrategy.fail` and try running this again you'll find that the stream almost immediately fails since the buffer is full:

```
[ERROR] [Buffer(akka://default)] Failing because buffer is full and overflowStrategy is: [Fail]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing in Akka Streams, I would use `mapAsync` and be careful not to use `.async` (as the latter, at least absent a custom `ActorMaterializer` or dispatcher for scheduling tasks, doesn't propagate backpressure that tightly).

```
object AkkaStreamLimitInflight {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("foo")
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import actorSystem.dispatcher

    val inflight = new AtomicInteger(0)

    def printWithInflight(msg: String): Unit = {
      println(s"$msg (${inflight.get} inflight)")
    }

    val source = Source.unfold(0) { state => 
      println(s"Emitting $state (${inflight.incrementAndGet()} inflight)")
      Some((state + 1, state))
    }.take(10)

    def quintuple(i: Int): (Int, Int) = {
      val quintupled = 5 * i
      printWithInflight(s"$i quintupled is $quintupled (originally $i)")
      (i, quintupled)
    }

    def minusOne(tup: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int) = {
      val (original, i) = tup
      val minus1 = i - 1
      printWithInflight(s"$i minus one is $minus1 (originally $original)")
      (original, minus1)
    }

    def double(tup: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int) = {
      val (original, i) = tup
      val doubled = 2 * i
      printWithInflight(s"$i doubled is $doubled (originally $original)")
      (original, doubled)
    }

    val toUnit = Flow[(Int, Int)]
      .map { case (original, i) =>
        println(s"Done with $i (originally $original) 
(${inflight.decrementAndGet()} inflight)")
        ()
      }

    val fut: Future[Done] = source
      .mapAsync(1) { i => Future { quintuple(i) }}
      .mapAsync(1) { tup => Future { minusOne(tup) }.map(double) }
      .via(toUnit)
      .runWith(Sink.ignore)


    fut.onComplete { _ => actorSystem.terminate() }
  }
}
```

In this case, the inflight count will never exceed 4 (one before the first `mapAsync` (due to operator fusion), one in the first `mapAsync`, one in the second `mapAsync`, and one after the second `mapAsync`).  If you want to limit the amount of inflight elements in particular stages, this is the way to go.

However, if all you want to do is limit the work in flight within the stream, moving the business logic into a single `Future` and spawning a bounded number of futures in `mapAsync` gives you just one knob to twiddle:

```
val fut: Future[Done] = source
  .mapAsync(5) { i =>
    Future { quintuple(i) }
      .map(minusOne)
      .map(double)
  }
  .via(toUnit)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I currently have the following: `source.via(parsing).via(component1).to(component2).run()`. In the parsing stage of my stream I don't want any restriction on the number of elements passing through it. Starting at the inlet of component 1 all the way to the sinks there should be a restriction of maximum 100 elements in flight for that whole part of the stream. I might also mention, component2 is a pretty complex component with partitions, broadcasts, a custom merge and multiple sinks. Don't know if that influences anything. Does your method work for this description?